# Do Solar Eruptions happen in more than one rotational "layer" in Sun's Differential Rotation?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, entropy, astrophysics, sun

Do Solar Eruption occupy more than one rotational layers? 
Is it possible to confirm this just for most outer layers? 
Does the number of layers occupied by those eruptions when they happen tell us anything about the relationship between Gravity and Entropy? 
 
#Update 
This is how i imagine Sun's Differential Rotation 
Each speed on the image has a different value

[image]

Comment: from this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare  solar eruptions happen in the atmosphere and are localized.

Comment: i do not understand the meaning of localized in this context. Does it mean that the solar eruption occupies layers ( on the Wiki article, it says all )  from Sun's atmosphere and inwards ? How about the Up and Down?  Correct me if i am wrong but i think that on the Sun's atmosphere at least, its rotation is separated in rings like Earth's equator with various width .

Comment: *At the equator, the Sun spins around once about every 25 Earth days, but at its poles, the Sun rotates once on its axis every 36 Earth days.* https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/solar-system/sun/in-depth/ in paragraph about "orbits and rotation". In paragraph "structure"   *The Sun has several regions. The interior regions include the core, the radiative zone, and the convection zone. Moving outward – the visible surface or photosphere is next, then the chromosphere, followed by the transition zone, and then the corona – the Sun’s expansive outer atmosphere.*

Comment: continue reading and you will see it is too complicated for your simplified expectations.

Comment: Here is a study about latitude and solar flares https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10509-019-3683-0 . *The solar flare events are tending to accumulate around a specific latitude line in the southern and northern hemispheres of the solar disk, which we call the “eruptive latitude”. The eruptive latitude is migrating towards the solar equator during the declining phase and away from the solar equator during the ascending phase.*

Comment: Thank you for the above. Do you "see" anything in that whole process that can give light onto the relationship between Gravity and Entropy?

Comment: Seems to me not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The Sun's "surface" (the photosphere) is [differentially rotating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_rotation#Differential_rotation_of_the_Sun) in the sense that the equatorial regions have a higher angular velocity than higher latitudes. This differential rotation is present throughout the outer convective zone of the Sun (roughly the outer 20% by radius). The differential rotation is continuous; the Sun is not separated into bands of rotation rate with discrete speeds as your diagram implies.

Most solar magnetic activity (e.g., sunspots and solar flares) occur at relatively low latitudes on the Sun - typically within $\pm 30^{\circ}$. The most active latitudes vary over the course of the [solar magnetic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cycle).

**Coronal mass ejections**, which is what I assume you mean by "solar eruptions", are often associated with eruptive flaring events but not always. They are thought to be regions of relatively strong magnetic field at their footpoints that become unstable. The energy source for the mass ejections is potential energy stored in the magnetic field structures that must have become stressed in some way. Differential rotation could be part of that stressing process - if magnetic loop footpoints are anchored at different latitudes in the photosphere, then that can generate a shear that builds up over days and ultimately results in a coronal mass ejection (e.g., [Lynch et al. 2016](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2016JA023432)). Coronal mass ejections that are triggered in this way are not necessarily associated with solar flares or sunspots and can occur at quite high latitudes on the Sun, especially at solar magnetic maximum when most coronal mass ejections occur (e.g., [Yashiro et al. 2004](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004JGRA..109.7105Y/abstract)). About 16% of coronal mass ejections occur at latitudes greater than 60 degrees ([Lin et al. 2022](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ac6f54/pdf)).

Comment: Rob, is there anything from the above that can somehow describe or define the relationship between Gravity and Entropy?